# Casting errors which occur in my JAVA code

Tags: java

I was wondering why is it impossible in java to pass interface instance to 'Object' parameter.
Following is my code.

```
interface Comparable_{
    public boolean greaterThan(Object obj);
}

class Max{
    public static Comparable_ max(Comparable_ obj1, Comparable_ obj2){
        if(obj1.greaterThan(obj2))//error occurs!
            return obj1;
        else
            return obj2;
    }
}

class Circle implements Comparable_{
    public boolean greaterThan(Object obj){
        if(this.radius > ((Circle)obj).radius)//error occurs
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public double radius;
}

public class JavaProgram{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Circle c1 = new Circle(); Circle c2 = new Circle();
        c1.radius = 3; c2.radius = 5;
        System.out.println( ((Circle)Max.max(c1, c2)).radius );
    }
}
```

And the error message is like following.
'The method greatherThan(Object) in the type Comparable_ is not applicable for the arguments (Comparable_)'
In my opinion, since obj2 is Comparable_ instance it is possible to pass obj2 to parameter,Object obj.
Please let me know what is wrong here :)

Comment: You might have to force the interface to inherit from Object, just my initial guess. Not an expert on the java type system

Comment: Interfaces do not extend class `java.lang.Object`. Only classes extend classes.

Comment: First of all, you cannot create an object of interface. That's the whole point of abstraction. For more information. Refer this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/interfaces-in-java/

Comment: Curious to know what if you changed `greather` (typo?) parameter type to `Comparable_` instead of `Object`.

Comment: Could you please add the full code, which leads to the error. Your statement is not correct and the point you mark as "here error occurs!" cannot fail as you describe, since it is totally ok. Your code is not executable so the error is not reproducible, so please update your question.

Comment: Have you defined your own type of `Object` anywhere?

Comment: Thank you all guys. I finally solved it by adding 'import java.lang.Object;' on the top of my code. It seems that vscode sees Object and java.lang.Object differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Test {

    interface Comparable_ {
        boolean greatherThan(Object obj);
    }

    static class SampleComparable implements Comparable_ {

        @Override
        public boolean greatherThan(final Object obj) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    static class Max {
        public  Comparable_ max(final Comparable_ obj1, final Comparable_ obj2) {
            if (obj1.greatherThan(obj2)) {
                return obj1;
            } else {
                return obj2;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Max max = new Max();

        System.out.println(max.max(new SampleComparable(), new SampleComparable()));
    }
}
```

I know this is not an answer to the question. But since I stated in the comment that the question is just incorrect, I would like to provide some "proof" for this statement. The following code can just be compiled and executed perfectly and it uses the same structure as presented in the question. So I assume the actually issue occurs somewhere else, but since the provided code is not executable or testable, it makes no sense to discuss this any further.

***Update:*** After providing the sample

Thanks for providing a better example. The provided code compiles and executes as expected, with the output `5.0`.

I assume that the error `The method greatherThan(Object) in the type Comparable_ is not applicable for the arguments (Comparable_)` you are seeing is a compiler error (and not a runtime error). Since you changed the naming of the method in your new example to `greaterThan` the error should now be `The method greaterThan(Object) in the type Comparable_ is not applicable for the arguments (Comparable_)`. I was not able to reproduce this exactly, but have a look at the following questions and maybe answering these will help you.

So the next questions are:

- Do you have anything else on your classpath, as mentioned in the comments if you have anywhere "your own `Object` type" this could lead to the mentioned issue (if I add such a class in, I get: `Error:(13, 29) java: incompatible types: Comparable_ cannot be converted to Object`

```
class Object {
  // ...
}
```

- How do you compile your code? It may be that you are having a malicious/broken/... library on your classpath (if you would, you normally would see the package name in the output, so I assume this is not the case).

Comment: I upvoted this answer. I also like how you maintained misspelling the words greater than in your sample too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i still have problem in my code and have no idea what's wrong with it.